# Finding the conditional distribution.

Tags: probability-distributions

A penny and dime are tossed. Let $X$ denotes the number of heads up. Then the penny is tossed again. Let $Y$ denotes the number of heads up on the dime(from the first toss) and the penny from the second one. We need to find the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X=1$ , i.e , $Y|X=1$;

In order to somehow simplify the situation I treated this as a coin tossed three times. Thus the sample space becomes : $\{HHH , HHT,HTH,THH,TTT,TTH,THT,HTT\}$

So the sample space for the event $Y|X=1$ becomes $\{HTH,THH,THT,HTT\}$

$$(Y|X=1) = \begin{cases}\dfrac{1}{4},& y=0\\ \dfrac{1}{2},& y=1\\ \dfrac{1}{4},&y=1\end{cases}$$

Is this correct?

Also $cov[X,Y]$ is also required , according to me it should be zero since the number of heads on the first toss doesn't depend on the number of heads on the second one.

Is the interpretation correct?

Comment: The covariance is not $0$ since $X=D+P$ and $Y=D+P'$ for independent $(D,P,P')$ Bernoulli random variables, hence Cov$(X,Y)=$Var$(D)=\frac14$.

Comment: Is the remaining interpretation correct ? @Did

Comment: Dunno, what do you call "the remaining interpretation"?

Comment: The function $(Y|X=1)$ ? @Did

Comment: This one is simple: the object $$(Y\mid X=1)$$ does not exist hence every solution requiring it is invalid.